# String split in golang

Tags: string, go, split

I have two arguments name and value, that I am trying to parse at runtime.

At run time I am passing the following values:

```
name = text,text,text,text,text
value = 0 ,285,404,6,24
```

Currently the output is as following;

```
Parameters: {"text,text,text,text,text":"0,285,404,6,24"}
```

when actually it must display as,

```
Parameters: {"text":"0"}
Parameters: {"text":"285"}
Parameters: {"text":"404"}
Parameters: {"text":"6"}
Parameters: {"text":"24"}
```

Following is my code;

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
   var m string
   var matchField = []string{"index,index,index,index"}
   var matchValue =[]string{"29,4,87,54"}

   for i := 0 ; i < 1 ; i++ {
        m = parameter(matchField[i], matchValue[i])
        fmt.Printf("Result: %s\n", m)
   }
}


func parameter(name string, value string) (matcher string) {
    var result string
    if name != "" || value != "" {
            result = fmt.Sprintf("{\"%s\":\"%s\"}", name, value)
    }
    return result
}
```

I wanted to know how to display the output accurately.

Comment: Have you looked at `strings.Split` (https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split)? Should be the first result if you googled how to split strings in go.

Comment: Yes I did. using strings.Split, i can split name and value by , but how to join them with {name:value} ?

Comment: You're already joining them in the sample code you gave. It seems like you're trying to produce JSON-formatted output though, so I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use `encoding/json` to do so.

Comment: No its not json formatted, Its simple string

Comment: JSON is just a string, and the string you're already producing in the example code is valid JSON. Regardless... what is the issue you're having with the method you're already using?

Comment: even then the output is as follows; {"text":0,"text":285}

Comment: OK? Could you clarify your question to indicate what output you need and how it's different from the output you're getting? The description and the code in the question don't match so it's hard to tell what your issue/question really is.

Comment: The expected output should be; Parameters: {"text":"0"}
Parameters: {"text":"285"}
Parameters: {"text":"404"}
Parameters: {"text":"6"}
Parameters: {"text":"24"}

Comment: Current output is Parameters : {"text":0,"text":285}

Comment: Current output is Parameters : {"text":0,"text":285}

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/b5rffvBUwqd

Comment: There is no way that the code you posted would be able to produce the output you gave in your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `strings.Split` to create the array, instead of an array with a single element:

[play.golang.org/p/b5rffvBUwqd](http://play.golang.org/p/b5rffvBUwqd)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
   var m string
   matchField := strings.Split("index,index,index,index", ",")
   matchValue := strings.Split("29,4,87,54", ",")

   for i := 0 ; i < len(matchField); i++ {
        m = parameter(matchField[i], matchValue[i])
        fmt.Printf("Parameters: %s\n", m)
   }
}


func parameter(name string, value string) (matcher string) {
    var result string
    if name != "" || value != "" {
            result = fmt.Sprintf("{\"%s\":\"%s\"}", name, value)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: The condition should be: `i < len(matchField) && i < len(matchValue)`.